# Oracle, ORDER BY with view results in error

Tags: oracle, view, sql-order-by, ora-00979

I'm selecting data from a view with the following query

```
SELECT * FROM "SCH"."MyView"
```

If I add ORDER BY

```
SELECT * FROM "SCH"."MyView"
ORDER BY Name
```

I get the following error

```
[Err] ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Does the Oracle query engine translate this to an invalid query? How would one start troubleshooting something like this?

Here is a simplification of the "SCH"."MyView"

```
SELECT
    Name,
    (subquery) AS Foo,
    (subquery) AS Bar
FROM
    "SCH"."AnotherView"
GROUP BY 
    Name
```

If I remove the subqueries, I can use ORDER BY without errormessages. Subqueries are as follows:

```
( SELECT f.UnitPrice FROM "SCH"."AnotherView" f WHERE f.Name = main.Name AND f.Category = 'x' AND rownum < 2 ) AS priceX
( SELECT b.UnitPrice FROM "SCH"."AnotherView" b WHERE b.Name = main.Name AND b.Category = 'y' AND rownum < 2 ) AS priceY
```

**Edit:** if I add "WHERE rownum < 9999999", I get rid of the error. We're running version 10.2.0.4.0 64bit.

Comment: can you post the view-definition as well? (if it is not too large)

Comment: Whats in MyView? Most probably your MyView is using a GROUP BY within.

Comment: The view has GROUP BY, also column Name is in the GROUP BY.

Comment: post the `VIEW` code that you have...

Comment: The view is quite large, comining several other views etc, so I don't it can be debugged in the comment section.. But am I to understand that Oracle can mess up a scenario like this when it's building the final query?

Comment: @Morri, you can edit your question to add the view definition. There's no need to add it to the comments.

Comment: Also if it looks like a bug, add your version/OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you tried to execute a `SELECT` statement that included a `GROUP BY` function (ie: `MIN`, `MAX`, `SUM`, `COUNT`) and an expression in the `SELECT` list that was not in the `GROUP BY` clause.